# Difference Between WHERE FIND_IN_SET(...)>0 and WHERE FIND_IN_SET(...)

Tags: mysql

According to [MySQL Reference Manual - The SET Type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/set.html)

> Normally, you search for SET values using the FIND_IN_SET() function or the LIKE operator:
>
> mysql> SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE FIND_IN_SET('value',set_col)>0;

According to [MySQL Reference Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

> FIND_IN_SET(str,strlist)
>
> Returns a value in the range of 1 to N if the string str is in the string list strlist consisting of N substrings. A string list is a string composed of substrings separated by “,” characters. If the first argument is a constant string and the second is a column of type SET, the FIND_IN_SET() function is optimized to use bit arithmetic. Returns 0 if str is not in strlist or if strlist is the empty string. Returns NULL if either argument is NULL.

Therefore, I think that

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE FIND_IN_SET('value',set_col)
```

works properly when you want to find value from a set.

So why does example from MySQL Reference Manual explicitly comparing with `>0` ?

Is there any difference ?

Comment: In fact both are same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following two `WHERE` clauses:

```
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('value', set_col) > 0
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('value', set_col)
```

In the first one, if *any* of the entries in `sel_col` contains `value`, then the return value for `FIND_IN_SET()` will be some number greater than 0, otherwise it will be 0.  In other words, it will return `TRUE` if the `value` is found, and `FALSE` otherwise.

The second `WHERE` clause will evaluate to either `WHERE X`, where `X` is either 1 or greater, if `value` be found, or 0, if `value` be not found.  In MySQL, the value `0` is synonymous with `FALSE`, and a positive number of `1` or greater is synonymous with `TRUE` (see [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/boolean-literals.html)).

So these two `WHERE` clauses will behave identically.